# Volume mapped filebeat.yml permissions from Docker on a Windows host

Tags: windows, docker, virtualbox, docker-compose, filebeat

I'm trying to run the official 5.4.3 Filebeat docker container via VirtualBox on a Windows host. Rather than creating a custom image, I'm using a volume mapping to pass the `filebeat.yml` file to the container using the automatically created VirtualBox mount `/c/Users` which points to `C:\Users` on my host.

Unfortunately I'm stuck on this error:

> Exiting: error loading config file: config file ("filebeat.yml") can only be writable by the owner but the permissions are "-rwxrwxrwx" (to fix the permissions use: 'chmod go-w /usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml')

My docker-compose config is:

```yaml
filebeat:
  image: "docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:5.4.3"
  volumes:
   - "/c/Users/Nathan/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro"
   - "/c/Users/Nathan/log:/mnt/log:ro"
```

I've tried SSH-ing into the machine and running the `chmod go-w` command but no change. Is this some kind of permission limitation when working with VirtualBox shared folders on a Windows host?

Answer (score 6):

It looks like this is a side effect of the Windows DACL permissions system. Fortunately I only need this for a development environment so I've simply disabled the permission check by overriding the container entry point and passing the `strict.perms` argument.

```yaml
filebeat:
  image: "docker.elastic.co/beats/filebeat:5.4.3"
  entrypoint: "filebeat -e -strict.perms=false"
  volumes:
   - "/c/Users/Nathan/filebeat.yml:/usr/share/filebeat/filebeat.yml:ro"
   - "/c/Users/Nathan/log:/mnt/log:ro"
```

Comment: Note that you can use a relative path rather than an absolute path.